# get the value from pointer to pointer in struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a struct:

```
struct structname
{
    structname** link;
    int total;
}
```

I want to link `structname1` to `structname2`. What I did was:

```
int *ptr = &structname2;
structname1 -> link = &ptr;
```

Then I tried to access the link for `structname1` which is `structname2`:

```
structname *test = structname1 -> link;
```

Is this the correct way to do it? When I tried to print out, some unknown symbols printed. Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to do a linked list?

Comment: Your code shouldn't compile.

Comment: @JohnZwinck it's the same as structname1. They both use the same struct. They are both stored in a list so that when structname2 is defined, it wont overwrite the structname1. Then I want to link them together.

Comment: @staticx yeah. A circular linked list is what i'm trying to do

Comment: `structname1->link` is supposed to be of type `struct structname **`, which is different than the type `struct structname *`.  Using `int *` to hold an object of type `struct structname *` is a bad idea, and trying to use it as an object of type `struct structname **` is doomed to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do in the below way.

```
struct structname structname1, structname2; //define two structures structname1 and structname2 of type structname.
struct structname * ptr; // ptr is a pointer to struct of type structname.
struct structname ** ptr2 // ptr2 is a double pointer to struct of type structname.
ptr = &structname2; // ptr points to structname2
ptr2 = &ptr; // ptr2 points to ptr and ptr points to structname2;
structname1.link = ptr2; // now link is a double pointer to structname2.
```

Let me correct if i'm wrong or missing

Comment: how do I access the int total?

Comment: if you want to access total in structname1, you have to use structname1.total. if  you want to access total in structname2, you can use (**ptr2)->total

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of things wrong in your code. First, you got the type for `ptr` wrong: it should be `struct structname **` instead of `int *`.

But if you're trying to do a linked list, you don't need the double indirection level at all. This is most likely what you want:

```
struct structname
{
    struct structname *link;
    int total;
}
```

With that, linking `structname1` with `structname2` is then as simple as (assuming `structname1` and `structname2` are of type `struct structname`):

```
struct structname *ptr = &structname2;
structname1.link = ptr;
```

If `structname1` and `structname2` are of type `struct structname *`, then you need this instead:

```
struct structname *ptr = structname2;
structname1->link = ptr;
```

You could also drop the intermediate variable `ptr`, it's not of much use here.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct node {
    struct node *next;
    int cargo;
}

struct node *current, *last, *next;
unsigned char i;
current = (struct node*)(calloc(sizeof(struct node)));

for (last = current, unsigned char i = 5; i--;) {
    next = (struct node*)(calloc(sizeof(struct node)));
    next->cargo = i;
    last->next = next;
}
```

The above code is a very easy linked list. Note that I changed a couple of things compared to your code. I create the objects using `calloc`, that means that the objects will be allocated on the heap instead of the stack. This also doesn't require you to have explicit names for every element, a.k.a. node in the linked list. It also means it won't be destroyed when you leve the scope of the names. Of course you will need to free all the nodes later, when you don't need the list anymore.
Then you don't need a pointer to a pointer in the node, a simple pointer is sufficient. In your main program you should also use an appropriate pointer. Even though, all pointers are the same size and can be cast into each other, you should - whenever possible - usde the right type.
Here I create another 5 nodes in a loop to demonstrate how 'flexible this approach is'.

If you want to do a circular linked list, that is quite easy as well. Simply append these line:

```
next->next = current;
```